# How to list out the html element from object arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, json

This is the object array of Member Relation, which I get from the server:-

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "userId": "111111",
        "loginId": "person1",
        "data": [
            {
                "userId": "222222",
                "loginId": "person2",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "userId": "444444",
                        "loginId": "person4",
                        "data": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "userId": "333333",
                "loginId": "person3",
                "data": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, I need to convert into HTML below from above arrays. I want to create a MEMBER RELATION MAP.
How to group the value from above array dynamically into HTML element like below:

```
<ul id="ul-data">
  <li>person1
    <ul>
    <li>person2
      <ul><li>person4</li></ul>
    </li>
    <li>person3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Below is my way that trying to do so:

```
$vv = '';
$row = [];
foreach($map['data']['data'] as $key => $lvl1):
    if($lvl1['data'] != []):
        $vv .= '<li>'.$lvl1['loginId'];
        foreach($lvl1['data'] as $key2 => $lvl2):
            $vv .= '<ul><li>'.$lvl2['loginId'].'</li></ul></li>';
        endforeach;
     else:
        $vv .= '<li>'.$lvl1['loginId'].'</li>';
     endif;
endforeach;
$data['map'] = json_encode($vv);
```

The result I did which is incorrect due to the data is not loop dynamically:

```
<ul class="ul-data">
  <li>person2
      <ul><li>person4</li></ul>
 </li>
 <li>person3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried something to get this done? Please share the problem that you face rather than requesting for the solution. Please.

Comment: @SanthoshJ , Hi, I have updated my tried on the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use recursion to achieve your desired outcome. Here's a code sample:

```
$json = '{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "userId": "111111",
        "loginId": "person1",
        "data": [
            {
                "userId": "222222",
                "loginId": "person2",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "userId": "444444",
                        "loginId": "person4",
                        "data": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "userId": "333333",
                "loginId": "person3",
                "data": []
            }
        ]
    }
}';

$data = json_decode($json);

echo '<ul id="ul-data">';
echo "<li>".$data->data->loginId;

generateList($data->data->data);

function generateList($person) {

    if(count($person) < 1) {
        return;
    }
    echo "<ul>"; 
    foreach($person as $p) {

        echo "<li>" . $p->loginId ;
            generateList($p->data);
        echo "</li>";
    } 

    echo "</ul>";
}

echo "</li></ul>";
```

Comment: Is quite tricky to implement into codeigniter, but it definitely works. I converted into codeigniter MVC.